# Bigquery convert format of value from string to datetime

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to convert the following value '2022-05-28T11:26:27.951903549Z' from a string format to a datetime format. I have tried:

- ('%A %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S', eventTime) > Failed to parse input string "2022-05-28T09:03:19.725965325Z"

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use the date-time format strings allowed to parse in bigquery:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time

```
with sz as (
  select '2022-05-28T11:26:27.951903549Z' as t
)
select parse_datetime('%FT%R:%E*SZ', t) from sz
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input.
All our backend events are pushed into BQ and unfortunately in string format for datetime. Im cleaning and structuring the data and subsequently its stored in another table in BQ.

This means that the string "2022-05-28T09:03:19.725965325Z" is already in Google BQ so i cannot use the with statement.

Comment: so "with" statement is just an example for simulating the question to access the field & parse the string "date" values. I don't understand why we were given a -ve point on both the question & the answer with the linked duplicated question as well has that -ve point.